# install4j 5.1.15 fails to install with bundled java 1.8

Tags: install4j

After bundling java 1.8 with install4j installer 5.1.15 Windows installer fails with the error "could not use bundled jre".  Here's the log and the screen shot.  How do I go about fixing this?  Does install4j 5.1.15 support java 1.8?

```
> > 
> 
> number of sections: 6 size of optional headers: 240
> resSectionTableStart: 696 rawDataSize: 2048, rawDataOffset: 337408
> sun.locale.formatasdefault is true language/country is en_US
> GetTempPath returned 37 (last error 183) make dir returned -1 change
> working directory to C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop single instance
> mode semaphore name
> Local\c:_users_administrator_desktop_appsetup-windows64.exe, code 0,
> value 00000000000000C4 Init done Starting work number of sections: 6
> size of optional headers: 240 resSectionTableStart: 696 rawDataSize:
> 2048, rawDataOffset: 337408 starting at 339456 verifying integrity
> length 511851237 checksums: 1016977293 1016977293 1016977293
> 1016977293 GetTempPath returned 37 (last error 183) make dir returned
> -1 tempPath is C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ tempFile is C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp Temp dir3:
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520 native
> lib dir is  GetTempPath returned 37 (last error 183) make dir returned
> -1 Setting PATH (native libs) C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
> extracting files Included files: 43 extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4jruntime.jar
> (size: 1089384) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre.tar.gz
> (size: 57375399) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_7_1kt141w_rbrn3l.png
> (size: 3247) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_9_1kt141w_lfnz23.png
> (size: 3359) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_2_1kt141w_1xde6yj.ico
> (size: 42284) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_5_1kt141w.txt
> (size: 41928) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_3_1kt141w_19ea1m4.png
> (size: 53069) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_8_1kt141w_1a0sp05.png
> (size: 807) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\stats.properties
> (size: 46864) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_0_1kt141w.utf8
> (size: 88592) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user.jar
> (size: 362515) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_4_1kt141w_1t7cvi5.png
> (size: 48012) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4jparams.conf
> (size: 1744206) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\platform.zip
> (size: 70484) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\nse.jar
> (size: 326684) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\jcmFIPS.jar
> (size: 522566) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\libsigar-ia64-linux.so
> (size: 494929) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\nsc.jar
> (size: 2389125) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\background.png
> (size: 53069) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\libsigar-amd64-linux.so
> (size: 246605) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\sigar.jar
> (size: 428580) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\nexserv.ico
> (size: 42284) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\cryptojcommon.jar
> (size: 1409784) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\sigar-amd64-winnt.dll
> (size: 402432) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\Cancel-icon2.png
> (size: 3359) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\io.jar
> (size: 11583) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\progress.gif
> (size: 1924) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\expanded-icon.png
> (size: 235) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\sigar-x86-winnt.dll
> (size: 266240) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\guava.jar
> (size: 2256213) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\lang.jar
> (size: 22852) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\Warn-icon2.png
> (size: 3247) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\cryptojce.jar
> (size: 58591) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\r7shared.jar
> (size: 4817064) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\nxshared.jar
> (size: 5022103) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\Check-icon2.png
> (size: 3302) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\collapsed-icon.png
> (size: 237) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\sslj.jar
> (size: 421576) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\sigar-x86-winnt.lib
> (size: 99584) creating directory
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user
> extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\user\libsigar-x86-linux.so
> (size: 233385) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_1_1kt141w.utf8
> (size: 55859) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\i4j_extf_6_1kt141w.gif
> (size: 43) extracting
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\MessagesDefault
> (size: 32732) extracting files done Current working dir:
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520 Full
> JRE path:
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre.tar.gz
> JRE included extracting JRE extracting jre1.8.0_31\bin\awt.dll (size
> 1519528) extracting jre1.8.0_31\bin\dcpr.dll (size 160168) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\decora_sse.dll (size 86440) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\deploy.dll (size 569256) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\dtplugin\deployJava1.dll (size 1013672) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\dtplugin\npdeployJava1.dll (size 1141160) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\dt_shmem.dll (size 30120) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\dt_socket.dll (size 25000) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\eula.dll (size 136616) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\fontmanager.dll (size 275368) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\fxplugins.dll (size 187816) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\glass.dll (size 261544) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\glib-lite.dll (size 456616) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\gstreamer-lite.dll (size 622504) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\hprof.dll (size 158120) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\instrument.dll (size 123816) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\j2pcsc.dll (size 19368) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\j2pkcs11.dll (size 63912) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jaas_nt.dll (size 21416) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jabswitch.exe (size 34216) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\java-rmi.exe (size 15784) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.dll (size 157096) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe (size 190888) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\JavaAccessBridge-64.dll (size 142760) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\javacpl.cpl (size 169984) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\javacpl.exe (size 77224) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\javafx_font.dll (size 75176) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\javafx_font_t2k.dll (size 540584) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\javafx_iio.dll (size 137128) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe (size 191400) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaws.exe (size 319912) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\java_crw_demo.dll (size 30120) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jawt.dll (size 14760) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\JAWTAccessBridge-64.dll (size 15784) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jdwp.dll (size 201640) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jfr.dll (size 25512) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jfxmedia.dll (size 139688) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jfxwebkit.dll (size 20753832) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jjs.exe (size 15784) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jli.dll (size 159144) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jp2iexp.dll (size 290216) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jp2launcher.exe (size 100264) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jp2native.dll (size 20392) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jp2ssv.dll (size 212904) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jpeg.dll (size 185768) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jsdt.dll (size 18856) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jsound.dll (size 35752) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\jsoundds.dll (size 31656) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\kcms.dll (size 221096) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\keytool.exe (size 15784) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\kinit.exe (size 16296) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\klist.exe (size 16296) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\ktab.exe (size 16296) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\lcms.dll (size 231848) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\management.dll (size 37288) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\mlib_image.dll (size 654248) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\msvcr100.dll (size 829264) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\net.dll (size 94120) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\nio.dll (size 59816) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\npt.dll (size 19368) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\orbd.exe (size 16296) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\pack200.exe (size 16296) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\plugin2\msvcr100.dll (size 829264) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\plugin2\npjp2.dll (size 228776) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\policytool.exe (size 16808) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\prism_common.dll (size 57768) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\prism_d3d.dll (size 166312) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\prism_es2.dll (size 47528) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\prism_sw.dll (size 64936) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\rmid.exe (size 15784) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\rmiregistry.exe (size 16808) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\server\jvm.dll (size 8569768) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\server\Xusage.txt (size 1423) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\servertool.exe (size 16808) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\splashscreen.dll (size 234920) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\ssv.dll (size 551848) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\ssvagent.exe (size 66472) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\sunec.dll (size 135080) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\sunmscapi.dll (size 31656) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\t2k.dll (size 253352) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\tnameserv.exe (size 16296) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\unpack.dll (size 80296) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\unpack200.exe (size 197544) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\verify.dll (size 49576) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\w2k_lsa_auth.dll (size 24488) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\WindowsAccessBridge-64.dll (size 111016) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\wsdetect.dll (size 192424) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\bin\zip.dll (size 77736) extracting jre1.8.0_31\COPYRIGHT
> (size 3244) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\accessibility.properties (size
> 155) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg (size 634) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\calendars.properties (size 1378) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\charsets.jar (size 3087946) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\classlist (size 80761) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\cmm\CIEXYZ.pf (size 51236) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\cmm\GRAY.pf (size 632) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\cmm\LINEAR_RGB.pf (size 1044) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\cmm\PYCC.pf (size 274474) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\cmm\sRGB.pf (size 3144) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\content-types.properties (size 5548) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\currency.data (size 4074) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\ffjcext.zip (size 14130) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages.properties (size 2860) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_de.properties (size 3306) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_es.properties (size 3600) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_fr.properties (size 3409) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_it.properties (size 3223) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_ja.properties (size 6349) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_ko.properties (size 5719) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_pt_BR.properties (size 3348)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_sv.properties (size 3409)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_zh_CN.properties (size
> 4072) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_zh_HK.properties
> (size 3752) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\messages_zh_TW.properties (size 3752)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy\splash.gif (size 65995) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\deploy.jar (size 2150451) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar (size 187471) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar (size 3860522) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\dnsns.jar (size 8286) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\jaccess.jar (size 44115) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar (size 17102367) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\localedata.jar (size 1179653) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\meta-index (size 1461) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\nashorn.jar (size 1618832) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\sunec.jar (size 39773) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar (size 278033) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar (size 32654) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar (size 249280) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\ext\zipfs.jar (size 68836) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\flavormap.properties (size 3928) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\fontconfig.bfc (size 3670) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\fontconfig.properties.src (size 10479) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaBrightDemiBold.ttf (size 75144) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaBrightDemiItalic.ttf (size 75124)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaBrightItalic.ttf (size 80856)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaBrightRegular.ttf (size 344908)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaSansDemiBold.ttf (size 317896)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaSansRegular.ttf (size 698236)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaTypewriterBold.ttf (size
> 234068) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\fonts\LucidaTypewriterRegular.ttf
> (size 242700) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\hijrah-config-umalqura.properties (size 13962)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\cursors.properties (size
> 1280) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\invalid32x32.gif (size
> 153) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\win32_CopyDrop32x32.gif
> (size 165) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\win32_CopyNoDrop32x32.gif (size 153)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\win32_LinkDrop32x32.gif
> (size 168) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\win32_LinkNoDrop32x32.gif (size 153)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\win32_MoveDrop32x32.gif
> (size 147) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\images\cursors\win32_MoveNoDrop32x32.gif (size 153)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\javafx.properties (size 29) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\javaws.jar (size 464133) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\jce.jar (size 113593) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\jfr\default.jfc (size 19264) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\jfr\profile.jfc (size 19220) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\jfr.jar (size 559333) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\jfxswt.jar (size 32982) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\jsse.jar (size 622403) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\jvm.hprof.txt (size 4226) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\logging.properties (size 2455) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\management\jmxremote.access (size 3998) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\management\jmxremote.password.template (size 2856)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\management\management.properties (size
> 14097) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\management\snmp.acl.template (size
> 3376) extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\management-agent.jar (size 381)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\lib\meta-index (size 2126) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\net.properties (size 3070) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\plugin.jar (size 1010118) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\psfont.properties.ja (size 2796) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\psfontj2d.properties (size 10393) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\resources.jar (size 3487757) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\rt.jar (size 63097774) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\blacklist (size 3890) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\blacklisted.certs (size 1188) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\cacerts (size 94618) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\java.policy (size 2466) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\java.security (size 21746) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\javaws.policy (size 98) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\local_policy.jar (size 3527) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\trusted.libraries (size 0) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\security\US_export_policy.jar (size 3026) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\sound.properties (size 1210) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\tzdb.dat (size 102449) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\lib\tzmappings (size 8163) extracting jre1.8.0_31\LICENSE
> (size 40) extracting jre1.8.0_31\README.txt (size 46) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\release (size 527) extracting
> jre1.8.0_31\THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt (size 110114)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt (size 178400)
> extracting jre1.8.0_31\Welcome.html (size 955) untaring JRE was
> successful JRE dir:
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre
> LoadDLL (0,
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre, 0)
> Got JRE location
> C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\e4jC385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre
> (java exe: 0) MinVersion: 1.8, MaxVersion:  Trying to load JVM-DLL
> from
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\java.exe
> Setting PATH
> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin
> Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\hotspot\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\classic\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\jrockit\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Setting PATH
> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
> Setting PATH
> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\..\jre\bin
> Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\..\jre\bin\hotspot\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\..\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\..\jre\bin\classic\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Trying
> c:\users\admini~1\appdata\local\temp\e4jc385.tmp_dir1423169520\jre\bin\..\jre\bin\jrockit\jvm.dll
> (exists 0) Setting PATH
> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
> ERROR: Could not get DLL-Handle. ERROR: Could not load functions
> ERROR: Could not load bundled JRE. Trying to find another JRE. LoadDLL
> (0, (null), 0) Searching for a JVM GetTempPath returned 37 (last error
> 3) make dir returned -1 Testing location .\_jvm1.8.0_31 (type R)
> checkJavaExe
> (c:\users\administrator\desktop\_jvm1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe, [out], 1.8,
> , 1) file doesn't exist checkJavaExe returning 0 GetTempPath returned
> 37 (last error 183) make dir returned -1 Testing location  (type Y)
> GetTempPath returned 37 (last error 183) make dir returned -1 Testing
> location JAVA_HOME (type E) GetTempPath returned 37 (last error 203)
> make dir returned -1 Testing location JDK_HOME (type E) Testing
> relative location .\_jvm1.8.0_31 Search sequence finished ERROR: No
> JVM found ERROR: Could not find another JRE.
```

[image]

[image]

[image: I got this error after installing the unlimited strength policy JAR files and repackaging the jre]

[image]

Comment: Try to cd to the bin folder of the extracted JRE and execute `java -version` to see what it says. If you have a 32-bit Windows, a 64-bit JRE bundle will not work.

Comment: It's a 64-bit JRE bundle on a 64-bit Windows 2008 server (see attached screenshot)

Comment: And the media file, is it a 64-bit media file as well? See the "32-bit or 64-bit" step of the media wizard.

Comment: Yes it is a 64-bit media file (Generate 64-bit executables is checked off)

Comment: Actually, the paths of the extracted JRE are wrong, the "jre1.8.0_31\" prefix should not be there. Did you prepare the JRE bundle manually?

Comment: Yes.  It was manually prepared.

Comment: Then there is a mistake in the structure of the tar file. The bin directory must be directly in the root of the tar file.

Comment: Thank you Ingo.  That fixed the issue but now there's a different issue when I manually update the unlimited strength policy JAR files (local_policy.jar, US_export_policy.jar in jre/lib/security), the installation fails with: `Full JRE path: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\2\e4j2BEA.tmp_dir1424817093\jre.tar.gz
JRE included
extracting JRE
ERROR: no magic number
ERROR: untaring JRE was unsuccessful
ERROR: Could not untar JRE
`

Comment: I tried repackaging on a linux machine instead of windows and I get a different error `JRE included
extracting JRE
extracting Welcome.html (size 955)
extracting THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt (size 110114)
extracting THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt (size 178400)
extracting release (size 527)
extracting README.txt (size 46)
extracting LICENSE (size 40)
extracting COPYRIGHT (size 3244)
extracting lib\images\cursors\cursors.properties (size 1280)
ERROR: Could not open file lib\images\cursors\cursors.properties`

Comment: I would suggest to use http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm for tarring on Windows.